# PGError: ERROR: relation "companies" does not exist( postgresql , mysql, rails 3)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql

Recently i added PostgreSQL to my application which was already running on MySQL, now application is running on two databases. I was able to establish associations between the tables present in different database and its working fine. Today i added a search feature in a page which uses tables present in two databases and its throwing an error. Spent all day trying to figure out the bug but didn't succeed. Please look into the associations,code and help me correct it.

I have 4 tables:-

Company(mysql)

Location(mysql)

Report(PostgreSQL)

Report_category(PostgreSQL)

model - company.rb

```
establish_connection Rails.env+"_postgres"
has_many :reports

establish_connection Rails.env
belongs_to :location
```

location.rb

```
has_many :companies
```

report.rb

```
establish_connection Rails.env
belongs_to :company

establish_connection Rails.env+"_postgres"
belongs_to :report_category
```

report_category.rb

```
establish_connection Rails.env+"_postgres"
has_many :report
```

Now from view i pass the search parameters and in my reports_controller i write

```
@reports = Report.where("companies.name like ? and report_category.name ?", params[:company], params[:category]).includes(:company, :report_category)
```

after executing this line i'm getting the below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
```

but

```
Company.where("location.name like ?", params[:location]).includes(:location)
```

or

```
Report.where("report_categories.name like ?", params[:category]).includes(:report_category)
```

works perfectly fine. I only get the error if i search using two databases. Please do help

Comment: Somehow I doubt rails is smart enough to pick apart the argument and realize you're using two different DBMS systems entirely within the same query, and it's sending the whole thing only to postgres. Since postgres doesn't anything at all about what's in mysql, it's rightfully complaining there's no "companies" table.

Comment: Why on earth do you have some tables in MySQL and others in PostgreSQL. You should have everything in one of them.

Comment: @MarcB so there is no solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Application is running from past 3 years on mysql and recently a huge data is entering into this application so we decided to use postgresql seeing its performance on large data... we are not in position to take risk by moving the entire mysql data to postgresql.

Comment: In my opinion that's a rather "questionable" strategy. You either do the migration or you don't. Besides all the problems you will hit (as you have just discovered) that setup will not give you any real indication whether PostgreSQL will better fit your requirements or not.

Comment: Echo a horse with no name...postgres is a separate language from the t-sql that mysql uses for starters.  What are you considering 'big data'?  MySQL is scalable into the terabytes before it reaches logical limits.  If you are hitting these large data sets, postgres isn't the best alternative, you may want to consider data warehouse appliances such as netezza from IBM or a columnar style database such as Vertica.  Would strongly recommend you re-think this stretegy

Answer (score 0):

First I want to second the suggestion in the comments that you move everything onto one db.  This saves you a lot of complexity down the road.  However if you really can't do this, there are a couple ways you can access the MySQL tables from within PostgreSQL, and this would be a second-class solution to a full migration, but it would work.

In PostgreSQL 9.1 and higher you can do read-only queries using foreign data wrappers for MySQL.  In earlier versions you can use David Fetter's DBI-Link project to make the connection.

These then allow you to present your data as a unified database to your applications.